# How to create expression to evaluate AND condition with multi expression?

Tags: css

How to use media query to check condition if view port width greater 578px and orientation portrait then width greater and orientation landscape, do something? if check popular device views port in this website https://viewportsizer.com/devices/. it show, in portrait popular device for mobile not greater 600px. but the landscape viewport crash with tablet view port portrait. but, if can check orientation view port, then can compare it. it solve that problem.

```
@media (min-width: 578px and orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 578px and orientation: landscape) { // css query }
```

Comment: Your phrasing is hard to understand, I can't tell what exactly you want to achieve. But that `(... and orientation: portrait) and (... and orientation: landscape)` makes little sense with the `and` in between the two parts, should be obvious - orientation can hardly be portrait _and_ landscape at the same time.

Comment: @CBroe we know to give some condition like to check only portrait condition. `(min-width: 578px) and (orientation: portrait)` . but i want to check 2 orientation in same time. so i can know if the width is tablet or mobile width. cause mobile width not greater from 600px in portrait orientation. if only single condition check orientation. the query works on 2 type device.

Comment: The orientation _can_ only be landscape, or portrait - so what sense is _"check 2 orientation in same time"_ supposed to make? If you want something to apply for _both_ landscape, and portrait - well then don't check for the orientation at all?

Comment: @CBroe in simple expresion it should like this `(x condition y) condition (a condition b) = result`. so x and y should true. a and b should true. then, execute query css.

Comment: But your `y` (`orientation: portrait`) and your `b` (`orientation: landscape`) are mutually exclusive. So of course any condition that joins them with AND, _can't_ be true.

Comment: @CBroe the sense u can know if the device is tablet or mobile. i make example, samsung galaxy ultra 20 have width 480 in portrait. and height 1067 in landscape. in tablet the lowest viewport microsoft surface book the width is 667 in portrait. 1000 in landscape.  in simple media query. we just give 1 condition. but u should know 480px in mobile and 667 in tablet is different psyhical size. in mobile the screen width is 5.9cm, in tablet it will like 7.5cm.

Comment: @CBroe so the css media query cant check 2 condition orientation in same time and execute query? so i need to use javascript to detect that in first place? like auto orientation user device to landscape and orientation it back to portrait and execute css query?

Comment: _"so the css media query cant check 2 condition orientation in same time"_ - you can not _demand_ that the `orientation` should be `portrait` _and_ `landscape` at the same time, that simply makes no sense - what about that is so hard to understand? This is the same, as if you had a number X, and now you go, "if X is divisible by 2, and X is not divisible by 2 at the same time, do ..." - can't you see how that makes little sense?

Comment: @CBroe my problem is in landscape mode. cause, width in landscape mode. tablet and mobile already same. if can compare 2 condition orientation in same time. it can detect what this width landcape for. is tablet or mobile.

Comment: But _why_ would you need to know, whether this is a tablet or a mobile device? Primarily, you should be using media queries to properly align your content across the available space, rather than trying to target specific devices "classes" or anything like that.

Comment: @CBroe i know now, it cant achieve with css media query. the query only check when event trigger. it doesn't check in first place. and trigger it later.  i got the solution now in javascript. i think will check condition orientation at the first place. if orientation portrait. i will get the screen width and height. and compare. width greater than 600 and heigh greater than is means tablet. and execute query css.

Comment: @CBroe if u know the exact value to target. it better to make as suppose. except. the value is random. https://viewportsizer.com/devices/ is realiable in exact device viewport. cause, resolution in tablet vs mobile. is different in real size device. its better to give same experience as developer see in development monitor. let's say in my 24' full hd. i can calculate exactly each element size in real dimension. like cm. if i see my eyes is good. i want it use have same experience as my eyes see. ex, in my development image in monitor is 5cm. i want it 5cm too. cause i know all device minimal

Comment: @CBroe minimal device. lets say in 3.5 device. the size in portrait is 4.1cm. then i just target that the lowest width and share same exprience in higher size.